# reading variable value in play WS response scope

Tags: java, playframework, java-8, promise, playframework-2.3

```
void makePdfPage(String url, PdfContentByte contentByte){
    com.itextpdf.text.Font sans = UtilityMethods.getSansSerifFont(14);
    sans.setColor(80,147,225);
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(contentByte);
    ct.setSimpleColumn("Hello", 0, 780, 595, 830, 10, Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    try {
        ct.go();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



  Promise<WSResponse> out = notification.call(url);
    out.map(resp->{
        Map<String,Object> mapp= Json.fromJson(resp.asJson().get("list"), Map.class);
        PdfService.designPdf(mapp, contentByte);
        return resp;
    });
}
```

`contentByte` is going empty to `desginPdf`

Its going async so thats why its not having the value of contentByte, can any other way so i can synchronously  use or any other way to solve my problem.

```
WSResponse resp = out.get(10000);
```

getting fails

Comment: From where contentByte came from? it is a global variable? or it is available in the block of the response?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with Java promises, but based on my experience in Scala, I would've tried something like this:

```
Promise<WSResponse> out = notification.call(url);
WSResponse res = out.map(resp->{
  Map<String,Object> mapp= Json.fromJson(resp.asJson().get("list"), Map.class);
  PdfService.designPdf(mapp, contentByte);
  return resp;
});
//Do something with res
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare contentByte variable as **final**

```
void makePdfPage(String url, final PdfContentByte contentByte){
```

Additionally you should add a recover code for fail case

```
 map(...)
 .recover(new Function<Throwable,JsonNode>() {
   public JsonNode apply(Throwable ex) {
        if(Logger.isErrorEnabled()){
            Logger.error("retrieving api info",ex);
        }
        return null; //TODO
    }
  });
```